# Django: How to conditionally filter on foreignkey

Tags: django, django-queryset

Suppose I have some classes as follows:

```py
from django.db import models

REVIEW_RATING_CHOICES = (
    (5, 'Five'),
    (4, 'Four'),
    (3, 'Three'),
    (2, 'Two'),
    (1, 'One'),
)

class Publication(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Article(models.Model):
    publication = models.ForeignKey(Publication)
    content = models.TextField()

class Review(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article)
    rating = models.IntegerField(choices=REVIEW_RATING_CHOICES)
```

Suppose we want to highlight "really good" publications, which we're defining as ones where any article was immediately given a five star review.

How can I get a count of Publications where *any* of the *first* (ie earliest value for Review.date) reviews for an article were give 5 stars?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can nest subqueries, but I'd be worried about the performance of it.

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery, Exists

earliest_review = Review.objects.filter(article_id=OuterRef('id')).order_by('date')
initially_approved_articles = Article.objects.annotate(
    earliest_review_status=Subquery(earliest_review.values('status')[:1]),
).filter(
    earliest_review_status=APPROVED,
    publication_id=OuterRef('id'),
)
Publication.objects.annotate(
    has_initially_approved_article=Exists(initially_approved_articles),
).filter(
    has_initially_approved_article=True,
)
```

Comment: For clarity I updated the question replacing "status" with "rating".

Comment: What I provided should still work. Just adjust the status comparison with the rating.